# Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2017

I am working/studying on [sakila](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) database and I am trying to convert to T-SQL and use with SQL Server. I am having some issues converting a view from MySql to T-SQL.

I have checked most of the articles here telling to move out the aggregate function from the query but i can not understand it well what they mean.

In MySql, the view is like this:

```
CREATE VIEW `actor_info` AS 
select `a`.`actor_id` AS `actor_id`,`a`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,`a`.`last_name` AS `last_name`,
    group_concat(
        distinct concat(`c`.`name`,': ',
            (
                select group_concat(`f`.`title` order by `f`.`title` ASC separator ', ') 
                    from ((`film` `f`
                    join `film_category` `fc` on((`f`.`film_id` = `fc`.`film_id`))) 
                    join `film_actor` `fa` on((`f`.`film_id` = `fa`.`film_id`))) 
                    where ((`fc`.`category_id` = `c`.`category_id`)
                    and (`fa`.`actor_id` = `a`.`actor_id`))
             )) 
    order by `c`.`name` ASC separator '; ') AS `film_info`

    from (((`actor` `a` 
    left join `film_actor` `fa` on((`a`.`actor_id` = `fa`.`actor_id`)))
    left join `film_category` `fc` on((`fa`.`film_id` = `fc`.`film_id`)))
    left join `category` `c` on((`fc`.`category_id` = `c`.`category_id`)))
    group by `a`.`actor_id`,`a`.`first_name`,`a`.`last_name`
```

and I have tried in T-SQL with this:

```
CREATE VIEW [actor_info] 
AS
    SELECT 
        a.first_name AS [First Name], a.last_name AS [Last Name],
        STRING_AGG(CONCAT(c.name,':',
                (
                    SELECT STRING_AGG(f.title, ', ')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY f.title)
                    FROM film f
                    join film_category fc ON f.film_id = fc.film_id
                    join film_actor fa ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
                    WHERE fc.category_id = c.category_id
                    and fa.actor_id = a.actor_id
                )
            ),';')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY c.name) AS [Film Info]
        FROM 
            actor a
        LEFT JOIN 
            film_actor fa ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
        LEFT JOIN 
            film_category fc ON fa.film_id = fc.film_id
        LEFT JOIN 
            category c ON fc.category_id = c.category_id
        GROUP BY 
            a.first_name, a.last_name
GO
```

Results I get from MySql database are in this format and I want to achieve the same in SQL Server:

```
first_name    last_name    film_info

PENELOPE       GUINESS     Animation: ANACONDA CONFESSIONS; Children: LANGUAGE COWBOY; Classics: COLOR PHILADELPHIA, WESTWARD SEABISCUIT; Comedy: VERTIGO NORTHWEST; Documentary: ACADEMY DINOSAUR; Family: KING EVOLUTION, SPLASH GUMP; Foreign: MULHOLLAND BEAST; Games: BULWORTH COMMANDMENTS, HUMAN GRAFFITI; Horror: ELEPHANT TROJAN, LADY STAGE, RULES HUMAN; Music: WIZARD COLDBLOODED; New: ANGELS LIFE, OKLAHOMA JUMANJI; Sci-Fi: CHEAPER CLYDE; Sports: GLEAMING JAWBREAKER;

NICK          WAHLBERG     Action: BULL SHAWSHANK; Animation: FIGHT JAWBREAKER; Children: JERSEY SASSY; Classics: DRACULA CRYSTAL, GILBERT PELICAN; Comedy: MALLRATS UNITED, RUSHMORE MERMAID; Documentary: ADAPTATION HOLES; Drama: WARDROBE PHANTOM; Family: APACHE DIVINE, CHISUM BEHAVIOR, INDIAN LOVE, MAGUIRE APACHE; Foreign: BABY HALL, HAPPINESS UNITED; Games: ROOF CHAMPION; Music: LUCKY FLYING; New: DESTINY SATURDAY, FLASH WARS, JEKYLL FROGMEN, MASK PEACH; Sci-Fi: CHAINSAW UPTOWN, GOODFELLAS SALUTE; Travel: LIAISONS SWEET, SMILE EARRING;
```

I can't figure out what is the correct syntax... appreciate if you can help/guide me on the correct syntax. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what the logic is supposed to be doing.

Comment: I have shown results i get from MySql database below. What else do you mean @GordonLinoff ??

Comment: I have provided all the info needed i believe and all the time in my questions i get downvotes....Why?

Comment: @NickStavrou simply posting 50 lines doesn't say what you actually want to do. People have to read all this and try to reverse engineer your intent. MySQL is notorious for its quirks, particularly around grouping and aggregations. A ***LOT*** of the code you see around are hacks trying to cover for the lack of the windowing functions that were introduced in MySQL 8.0

Comment: As for the result format, generating text like this is typically the job of the reporting engine, not SQL. It looks like you want to display Master records in a table and Detail records nested in each Master's line. Why use two levels of aggregation then? Or are you trying to nest something else too? Notice that I'm trying to guess what you're doing for almost 10 minutes

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos my intention wasn't to post 50 lines and wait for a guide or help or hack. I am trying to learn sql and understand it better. I just want to have the same result as i have shown in the result grid when i call that view.
What else can i write to be more accurate in my questions i do not know. I have posted all the data i believe i can share.
Τι άλλο χρειάζεται για να είναι σωστή αυτή η ερώτηση?

Comment: In any case, any reporting engine or client-side code could produce the desired result with far simpler code. For example, a report engine like SSRS can use nested lists and tables, using eg bullets and nice formatting for headers and values. That's impossible if you return a blob of text from the database. A web app could loop over child items and emit `<div>` or `<span>` sections as needed

Comment: @NickStavrou the MySQL query is problematic to begin with. It's not a good example to learn SQL nor should it be used in other databases.

Answer (score -1):

You have to do it with CTE in two times :

- First CTE concatenate category with an aggregation of actors
- Second CTE aggregate the results of the firts one

Comment: That doesn't answer the question. Besides, check the desired result - it's a nested Detail table inside the Master row